How does new Firebase Authentication billing work and why we need to "Upgrade to Firebase Auth with Identity platform to access this feature."?
My app supports only login via Email/Password and phone using Firebase Authentication.
Inside the Authentication -> Settings tab, Firebase said to me "Upgrade to Firebase Auth with Identity platform to access this feature."
firebase pricing
Here are my questions:

Is it compulsory to upgrade firebase auth as still without upgrading I'm able to get otp?

2.Regarding Firebase pricing for SMS:

Is the daily limit of 10 SMS applicable to both phone and email/password authentication combined, or is it separate for each?
If I upgrade to a pricing plan, how many SMS can I send per day?
How are charges applied? For example, if there are free SMS messages included in the plan, are they counted per OTP sent, or is there a cumulative limit for the day regardless of the number of OTPs sent? And if you exceed the free limit, how will the charges be calculated?

I attempted to clarify the requirements and limitations of Firebase Authentication for my app, which currently supports login via Email/Password and phone using Firebase Authentication. Despite receiving a prompt from Firebase to upgrade to Firebase Auth with Identity Platform for additional features, I wanted to confirm whether it's mandatory to upgrade for OTP functionality. Additionally, I sought clarification on Firebase's pricing for SMS authentication, particularly regarding the daily limit of 10 SMS messages, whether it's combined for phone and email/password authentication, the SMS limit upon upgrading to a pricing plan, and how charges are applied. My expectation was to gain clarity on these aspects to make informed decisions regarding Firebase Authentication for my app.
I hope everything is clear. Thank you.


you can still use email/password and phone auth without upgrading, with the limitation that you only get 10 SMS messages sent across your entire project (user base) per day.

email/password does not depend on SMS messages, unless you are enabling Multi Factor Authentication (MFA).


You ask about "phone" and OTP authentication, but it is unclear to me what you are referring to here.  Phone Auth uses SMS to send a code to the phone when attempting to log in.  "OTP" is somewhat ambiguous as there are several features of Firebase Auth that could be called "OTP", such as TOTP MFA, SMS MFA, or Passwordless/Email Link authentication.
